# How to Play a SCORM content in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, scorm1.2, moodle-mobile

I have tried to create a simple LMS to play a SCORM content in web. parsing the manifest file inside the SCORM zip you can get the target file and use that as src in frame and the Content plays and tracks.

example

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>VS SCORM - RTE Frameset</title>
    <!-- Rev 1.0 - Sunday, May 31, 2009 -->
</head>
<frameset 
  frameborder="0" framespacing="0" 
  border="0" rows="0,*" cols="*" >
    <frame src="api.html" name="API" noresize>
    <frame src="../course/course/index.html?type=scorm" name="course">
</frameset>
</html>
```

This works for web app. The api.html contains all standard SCORM functions like LMSInitialize, LMSCommit etc. I am trying to play SCORM in react-native and creating these functions.

I have tried with WebView and HTMLView but didn't worked.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @alan_langlois No didn't found

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71402028/how-to-recod-scorm-interactions-in-window-api-cmi-in-react-native

@RahulJain I also looking for this solution, let me know if get the solution.