# how to recod scorm Interactions in window.API.cmi in React Native

Tags: react-native, scorm, react-native-webview

I have the SCORM file and opened it using the package react-native-webview. I need to track the progress but when I injected the javascript to set the variables the catch part executed and the alert shows me **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.API.cmi)**

```
const injectTrack = () => {
const setTrackInjection = `
    try {
        window.API.cmi.core.student_id = "${user?.id ? user?.id : ''}";  
        window.API.cmi.core.student_name = "${user?.firstname ? user?.firstname : ''}";
        window.API.cmi.suspend_data = '${suspend_data}';
        window.API.cmi.core.total_time = '${total_time}';
        window.API.cmi.core.session_time = '${session_time}';
        window.API.cmi.core.score.raw = '${scoreRaw}';
        window.API.cmi.core.score.max = '${scoreMax}';
        window.API.cmi.core.score.min = '${scoreMin}';
        window.API.cmi.core.lesson_status = '${lesson_status}';
        window.API.cmi.core.exit = '${exit}';
        
    } catch(error){
        alert(error);
    }
    true;`;

webviewRef.current.injectJavaScript(setTrackInjection);
```

};

Comment: Is it running inside a SCORM player window? The SCORM player provides the API, rather than the package itself.

Comment: Basically, I'm using the react-native-webview for playing the scorm file.

Comment: I don't know what "react-native-webview" is, but I asked Google and it appears to be some sort of web browser equivalent. It's not a SCORM Player. 

That explains the error you are getting: window.API does not exist because the react-native-webview does not create an object called "API".

Comment: @Andrew, You are not familiar with React-Native?

Comment: That's correct.